# Bash Script to delete directories older than 5 days?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, ubuntu, cron

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>>/var/log/folderpurge.log 2>&1

date

###########################
# Self Explanatory printf #
###########################
if [[ ! $EUID == 0 ]]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root."
    exit 1
fi

########################################################################
# Check the current local(nix) folder size before initiating the purge #
########################################################################
if [ -e /home/s3user/extractedISOs/ ] && [ $(du -hsm    /home/s3user/extractedISOs | awk '{print $1}' -gt $((1024*50)) ]
then 
    echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    echo "| The extractedISOs folder exists and it is greater than 50GB |"
    echo "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    echo "++++++++++++++++++++"
    echo "| INITIATING PURGE |"
    echo "++++++++++++++++++++"
    #foldpurg=$(find /home/s3user/extractedISOs/* -type d -ctime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;);
    foldpurg=$(find /home/s3user/extractedISOs/* -type d -ctime +5 | xargs rm -rf);
else
    exit
fi

exit 0


**Error at line 20 and 35?**
```

Comment: share the exact error given ?

Comment: clue : the number of opening brackets needs to match the number of closing brackets.

Comment: 1 Thu Jul  6 10:53:14 EDT 2017
      2 ./purgery.sh: line 20: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
      3 ./purgery.sh: line 35: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: sounds like might be an unmatched ')' then ?

Comment: Can you _include_ line numbers in the embedded code?

Comment: Ok so in line 20

Comment: There is no closing parenthesis for `$(du -hsm`

Comment: $(du -hsm)                  would be correct?

Comment: No I think it should be: `$(du -hsm    /home/s3user/extractedISOs | awk '{print $1}') -gt $((1024*50))`

Comment: Will try this now @Jesse_b

Comment: @Jesse_b you misunderstood the code. It wasn't a single `$()`. It was a comparison so the `-gt ...` must not be included in the `()`

Comment: 30 ./purgery.sh: line 22: /home/s3user/extractedISOs: Is a directory
    31 awk: fatal: cannot open file `-gt' for reading (No such file or directory) 
    32 ./purgery.sh: line 21: [: 1: unary operator expected
    ~

Comment: @ADDB Yea I caught it and edited my comment.

Comment: @war132 See the edit to my comment.  The closing parenthesis needs to go after '{print $1}'

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm mistaken, you're missing the closing parenthesis to your du statement.

```
[ $(du -hsm    /home/s3user/extractedISOs | awk '{print $1}' -gt $((1024*50)) ]
```

The following should work:

```
[ $(du -hsm    /home/s3user/extractedISOs | awk '{print $1}' ) -gt $((1024*50)) ]
```

Comment: `49 Mon Jul 17 14:48:00 EDT 2017
    50 ./purgery.sh: line 22: /home/s3user/extractedISOs: Is a directory
    51 awk: fatal: cannot open file `-gt' for reading (No such file or 
       directory)
    52 ./purgery.sh: line 21: [: 1: unary operator expected
    ~`

Comment: @war132 `[ $(du -hsm    /home/s3user/extractedISOs | awk '{print $1}' ) -gt $((1024*50)) ]` he made a mistake, try this.

Comment: One issue is that you're missing a parathensis, the other is that you need quotes to do the comparison.    `[ "$(du -hsm /home/s3user/extractedISOs | awk '{print $1}' ))" -gt $((1024*50)) ]`    @ADDB, you're right, I put the missing parens in the wrong spot - I assumed it went at the end.

Comment: `53 Mon Jul 17 14:59:08 EDT 2017
 54 ./purgery.sh: line 22: /home/s3user/extractedISOs: Is a directory
 55 ./purgery.sh: line 21: [: too many arguments
~`

Comment: @foobaru you are not the friend of parenthesis are you? `"$(du ... | awk {} )")` where is the `)` after the `"` coming from?^^

Comment: @ADDB, the parens and the double quote were transposed. It's been fixed.

Comment: Still the 2. `)` is wrong @foobaru. @war132 did you change something in the script? The `line 22` makes me curious. It is a line with an echo statement.

Comment: Line 22 is a then statement.